# How to add a table to the model?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Used by:
- VS 2017;
- Win 7x64;
- MS Sql Server 2012;
- EntityFramework - 6.2.0;

**Model**
[image]

**Table "tbl_xx"**

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo]. [Tbl_xx] (
       [Field] int NULL
    )
    ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
     
    ALTER TABLE [dbo]. [Tbl_xx] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE
)
```

I try to add a table to the model
 [image]
 [image]
[image]

Table not added.

**Questions**
1. Am I doing everything correctly to add a table to the model?
2. How to add a table to the model?

**Update_1**
I closed the opened VS.
No result.

**Update_2**
Added a key to the table.
The table began to be added

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_xx] (
      [Field] int  NULL,
      [id] int  NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK__tbl_xx__3213E83FEB4094A9] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id])
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)  
    ON [PRIMARY]
    )  
    ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_xx] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
```

Comment: Have you tried closing Visual Studio and opening it again?

Some times it simply doesn't show up without restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: @Stemado I closed, opened the sun.
There is no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a class to be generated by EntityFramework the table/view needs to have a primary key column. You did already find this out. Also if you would investigate the XML of the .edmx file you would notice a commented section informing you, that EF couldn't identify a primary key for that table and therefore didn't generate anything.

When using EF I would consider a best practice for all tables to have `IDENTITY` columns with a `PRIMARY KEY` specified on them.

For the views it might be a bit more complicated, but you can still adjust the XML of the .edmx file to specify the `key` columns.

I would also suggest explicitly naming all DB keys (primary and foreign) and also all constraints for future maintenance and portability - the generated names will be different on different DBs and this could lead to complications later.